# How to speed up python execution? Multiprocessing is not working

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to do multiprocessing to speed up feature extraction process.
Here is what I have done:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process
import time


def cal_feature(subject):
    return (np.mean((subject),axis=-1))

#multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    st=time.time()
    data_1= np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(300, 100, 2000))
    data_2= np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(300, 100, 2000))
    data_3= np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(300, 100, 2000))
    data_4= np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(300, 100, 2000))
    data_5= np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(300, 100, 2000))
    data={1:data_1,2:data_2,3:data_3,4:data_4,5:data_5}
    p=Pool(10)
    parallel_result=[]
    for i in data.keys():
        result=p.map(cal_feature, np.split(data[i], 10))
        parallel=np.concatenate((result),axis=0)
        parallel_result.append(parallel)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print('multprocessing total time',time.time()-st)
```

---

```
#Serial processing
st=time.time()
data_1= np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(300, 100, 2000))
data_2= np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(300, 100, 2000))
data_3= np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(300, 100, 2000))
data_4= np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(300, 100, 2000))
data={1:data_1,2:data_2,3:data_3,4:data_4,5:data_5}
series_result=[]
series=[]
for i in data.keys():
    series_result.append(cal_feature(data[i]))

print('series toal time',time.time()-st)
```

But multiprocessing takes 5 times longer than series programming. How can I speed-up my feature extraction? Here I am using `numpy.mean` as a feature, but in real data set I have 30 complex feature functions. Instead of 5 data-sets randomly generated, I have 80 such sets. Is there a way to do robust feature extractions?

Comment: Don't start pool.map on each iteration - make a single map call. And don't split `np.split(data[i], 10)`, pass `data[i]` to target function

Comment: On my system this is hardly using any CPU, it's spawned loads of processes, one of which is eating 2.3 GB of RAM, the rest nothing. So obviously not doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: I did not get this line. Don't start pool.map on each iteration - make a single map call. Can you please explain it

Comment: @TalhaAnwar, `result = p.map(cal_feature, data.values())` - without for loop

Comment: The point is that each process had to pickle pretty big array for each target processing - that makes a hit. Whereas the consecutive processing deals with initial array directly. With your input data I get 3 sec for consecutive approach and 6 sec for multiprocessing approach

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i have tried `result = p.map(cal_feature, data.values())` but that doesnot help  a lot

Comment: TalhaAnwar: Are your 80 data-sets also randomly generated?

Comment: No, they are not randomly generated. But they are as same as these dummy randomly generated data shape and stored in a dictionary same as `data` in my code @martineau

Answer (score 0):

The point is that each process had to pickle pretty big array for each *target* processing - that makes a hit. Whereas the consecutive processing deals with initial array directly. With your input data I get `3` sec for consecutive approach and `6` sec for multiprocessing approach.

Issues in your attempt: don't initiate `pool.map` on each iteration - make a single `map` call, cause it already implies processing an iterable of data items. And would not need to split data item `np.split(data[i], 10)`, but pass `data[i]` to a target function.

With that said, to get a real performance benefit from `multiprocessing` approach in your case - considering how's your input arrays are constructed, we need to prevent pickling of those capacious arrays and shift the responsibility of generating an array to a *target* function with just passing in array *size/shape* options:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time


def cal_feature(start, end, size):
    return np.mean(np.random.randint(start, end, size=size), axis=-1)


# multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    st = time.time()
    data_shapes = [(0, 100, (300, 100, 2000)),
                   (100, 200, (300, 100, 2000)),
                   (100, 200, (300, 100, 2000)),
                   (100, 200, (300, 100, 2000)),
                   (100, 200, (300, 100, 2000))]
    with Pool(10) as p:
        result = p.starmap(cal_feature, data_shapes)
        print('multprocessing total time', time.time() - st)
```

Time execution result: `multprocessing total time 0.6732537746429443` (against 3 seconds of consecutive processing)

[`pool.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) will return the needed accumulated results.

Comment: I think the way the input data is constructed in the OP's question is just for illustrative purposes — so what you say wouldn't really apply to processing real input data that cannot be generated on demand.

Comment: i am still strugling to map / implement this approach to my real data. Let me explain my read data. I have a dictionary saved as npy in disk. Each key in a dictionary represent data file (data_1, data_2, data_3 and so on) same as in case of randomly generated `data` dictionary. There are 80 such keys. Though the shape of each data is `(100,64,3072)` but they are float data type, making array heavy in size

Comment: @martineau, I can not forecast the real data, I saw the input data and presented a working solution, that's it